# Unable to upload an image using Swift

Tags: json, swift, http-post, nsurlsession

I am unable to upload an image using swift.  All the other information is inserted correctly into the database.  This function submit book details but it also needs to submit an image. How do I submit an image using my current swift code? Thanks.

```
func uploadOrder (completion: @escaping (Bool, Any?, Error?) -> Void) {

    let imageSize: CGSize = (self._book.imageView?.bounds.size)!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    self._book.imageView?.layer .render(in: context!)
    let myImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 90)! as NSData
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()



    let jsonDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    guard let url = URL(string: Constants.uploadOrder) else { return }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if let isbn = self._book.ISBN as String? {
        jsonDictionary.setValue(isbn, forKey:"isbn")
    } else {
         jsonDictionary.setValue("", forKey:"isbn")
    }

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDictionary, options: []) else {
        return
    }
    urlRequest.httpBody = httpBody
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print("Response", response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let status  = (json as AnyObject).value(forKey:"OK") as! Bool? {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { //GUI thread
                         completion(true, status, nil)
                    }
                }

            } catch  let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { //GUI thread
                    completion(false, nil, error)
                }
            }

        }
        }.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your image data to base64

```
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

and add it as value for a key to your jsonDictionary

```
jsonDictionary.setValue(base64String, forKey:"image")
```